# Change function in order to have a separate JS file - AJAX, HTML and MySQL

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ajax

I'm doing a project atm and I need to display a table from MySQL in a HTML page. I have code currently that is doing this but as I am using framework 7, I need to change the JavaScript function so that I can move the function to a separate `.js` file instead of having all the code in my HTML file. I literally want the code to do exactly what it's doing right now but just from two separate files, any ideas on how go change the function?

My code currently is;

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("https://cs1.ucc.ie/~lmm12/ProjectTraining/api.php",function(postresult){
    $("body").append(postresult);
    });
});

</script>




</head>
<body>

 
<h3>A jQuery post demo with MySQL DB and PHP</h3>

 
</body>
</html>
```

This is the corresponding PHP file increase that helps;

```html
<?php
//remove space in PHP tag 
$dbhostname = '--';
 
$dbusername = '--';
 
$dbpassword = '--';
 
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
 
if(! $conn )
 
{
 
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
 
}
 
//echo 'MySQL Connected successfully'."<BR>";
 
mysqli_select_db($conn, "--") or die(mysqli_error());
 
//echo "Connected to Database"."<BR>";
 
$emp_salary = 7000;
 
$emp_id = 3;
 
$sql_statemanet = "select * from food";
 
$rec_select = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_statemanet);
 
if(! $rec_select )
 
{
 
  die('Could not retrieve data: ' . mysqli_error());
 
}
 
//Displaying fetched records to HTML table
 
echo "<table class='demotbl'>";
 
echo "<tr> <th>Product ID</th> <th>Product </th> <th>Quality </th> <th>Quantity </th></tr>";
 
// Using mysql_fetch_array() to get the next row until end of table rows
 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $rec_select )) {
 
                // Print out the contents of each row into a table
 
                echo "<tr><td>";
 
                echo $row['name'];
 
                echo "</td><td>";
                
                echo $row['tfat'];
 
                echo "</td><td>";

                echo $row['calories'];
 
                echo "</td><td>";
                
                echo $row['type'];
 
                echo "</td></tr>";                                
 
}
 
mysqli_close($conn);
 
?>
```

Comment: Hi, do you want separate js from html right?

Comment: yes so that I can put it in a phonegap project

Comment: well i wrote a answer, i hope i was understand you

Answer (score 0):

If you want only separate js from html just put your js code in a js file:

**JS FILE:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("https://cs1.ucc.ie/~lmm12/ProjectTraining/api.php",function(postresult){
    $("body").append(postresult);
    });
});
```

and then you can invoke it in your html like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="path_of_your_js/your_js_file.js"></script>
```

Comment: because I'm using framework 7 I have a separate index.html file were I source all my other files so I need to changed the actual function. My html for displaying the database only has the body in it

Comment: look this, is like my answer https://v1.framework7.io/docs/get-started.html